# Identify new added records and modified ones in mysql database

Tags: python, html, mysql, pandas, flask

I have a database that looks like this, Now I do want to display new added records or modified records based on data entry on html page. Now the table is a long table and more variables can be added to one record id and also new record ids can be added with same variable names but different values. I do want to display on html new record ids and modified records based on values

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('4010000','age', 38),
                   ('4010000','t_seen', "10:00am"),
                   ('4010001','birth_w', 40),
                   ('4010001','birth_unit', "kg"),
                   ('4010002','baby_seen', 56),
                  ('4010002','admiss', 456)],
                  columns=('Record_id','variable', 'value'))
df
```

Anyone knows how I can do this in python here is how I am pulling this data from database using flask

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


app = Flask(__name__)


host   = 'localhost'
port   = port name
user   = ''
passwd = ''
db     = 'red_data'

@app.route('/tables')
def someName():
        cnx    = pymysql.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
        cur    = cnx.cursor()
        query  = "SELECT * FROM red_data"
        cur.execute(query)
        field_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
        get_data = [xx for xx in cur]
        cur.close()
        cnx.close()
        df = DataFrame(get_data)
        df.columns = field_names
        results = df
        return render_template('index.html', results=[results.to_html(classes='results')],
        titles = ['na', 'database table'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8585)
```

Here is my html output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <div class=page>
        <h1>Surfer groups</h1>
        {% for table in results %}
        <h2>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h2>
        {{ table|safe }}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would to display new and modified records on browser

Comment: Just a small clarification, do you want to display only new and/or modified records or do you want to sort them in a way where the latest records show first?

Comment: @– TheSynt4x Yes I want to sort so that new and modified records can be shown first

Comment: You could change your SQL query to order the result set in a descending order.

Comment: @ – TheSynt4x Could you kindly share a sample code I can try and use this end. I am a newbie

Comment: I can't unfortunately provide a code sample for your case however I can provide a sample SQL query that would suit your needs. `SELECT * FROM red_data ORDER BY created_at DESC`. You will need to create a `created_at` timestamp column in your table and set its default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. That way, any time you create a new record, it will always take the current date. After that, you can easily order by the date, whether it be in an ascending or descending order. You will have to re-populate your database however, but that's one of the solutions to your problem.